Webpage Only Scrolls Once Using Selenium Despite New Content Loading
I'm trying to scrape URLs from a dynamically allocated webpage that requires continuous scrolling to load all the content into the DOM. My approach involves running window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); in a loop using Selenium's execute_script function. After each scroll, I compare the number of URLs loaded before and after the scroll. If the number of URLs doesn't change, I assume the end of the page has been reached and break the loop.
However, the script assumes that all content has been loaded into the DOM, even though I know new content is being loaded within the given timeout. Below is my code:
def _scroll_page_to_bottom(self, timeout: int):  # Todo: Fix Bugs
    while True:
        urls_before_scroll = self.browser.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, read_xpath(self.scrape_programs_urls.__name__, "programs_urls")
        )
        self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait for new content to be loaded
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, timeout).until(
                lambda _: len(self.browser.find_elements(
                    By.XPATH, read_xpath(self.scrape_programs_urls.__name__, "programs_urls"))
                ) > len(urls_before_scroll)
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            # If no new content is loaded within the timeout, assume we've reached the end of the page
            break

Can anyone please guess what could be causing the issue in the above code?
Edit: i did some debugging and found the issue is specifically related to scroll functionality when i execute window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); in the console of the browser the page doesn't get scrolled to the bottom either which explains why my code is not working. The site am trying to scrape is https://hackerone.com/opportunities/all/search

Can you post the URL and tell us which element do you need to keep scrolling?

@vassiliev https://hackerone.com/opportunities/all/search

@vassiliev i did some debugging and found the issue is specifically related to scroll functionality the page only responds to mouse wheel actions or the down arrow key. i tried to simulate this using ActionChains and even pyautogui but none of them worked. Also my code was working earlier (2 days to be specific) so they must have changed the UI. As a side note when i execute window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); in the console the page doesn't get scrolled to the bottom which explains why my code is not working.

Selenium won't know when the scroll has finished or when the DOM has been re-populated.  Use a good amount of sleep afterwards.  And/or catch Stale Element exceptions while iterating and re-get the element reference array when caught.

@browsermator i think you are mistaken here i am already using WebDriverWait so the timeout argument will automatically set a delay and raise a TimeoutException when no new content is loaded within the given timeout. Nevertheless the page is not getting scrolled to bottom itself with the window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); javascript so the problem lies with scrolling instead.

This code below works well in scrolling down the page, try to embed it into your code:
ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class,"Pane-module_u1-pane__content")]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);', ele)


Thank you for your answer! But Could you please explain your approach as well?

@binary 1) I find the element that you wanna keep scrolling is <div class="Pane-module_u1-pane__content__??? Pane-module_u1-pane__content--no-padding__-???">, I use contain() function in xpath to locate  the element to privent the ??? part changes.
2) I use scrollIntoView() instead of scrollTo() in order to omit specify coordinates. scrollIntoView(false) means scroll to the bottom of that element (equals to scrollIntoView({block: "end", inline: "nearest"})

Thanks it does work but for some reasons it doesn't work with default window size of the browser instead it works when i set an specific window size for an example: driver.set_window_size(670, 670)
